# Ошибка при расхэшировании пароля для последующей аутентификации

Tags: python, django

Всем здравствуйте!

**Суть задачи:** проект предполагает функционал email-рассылки. Т.е. пользователю нужно сохранять почту и пароль от нее. Я сохраняю пароль в БД с помощью функции `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`. Но у меня не получается его расхэшировать для осуществления авторизации. Я пытался использовать функцию `identify_hasher`, но выдает ошибку `PBKDF2PasswordHasher.encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'salt'`, хотя судя по документации - такого обязательного аргумента функция не принимает.

Пытался позаимствовать код из пакетов, которые используются при работе контроллера `LoginView` и `AuthenticationForm` при авторизации пользователей сайта - но ничего подробного я там не смог найти.

Буду благодарен любому ответу!

Comment: Хэширование для того и существует, чтобы расхэшировать было в принципе невозможно

Comment: @andreymal логично. Как тогда работает авторизация пользователя?

Comment: Пришедший от пользователя пароль тоже хэшируется и сравнивается с хэшем из базы

Comment: В AuthenticationForm что-то всё очень сложно, но, насколько я понимаю, всё по итогу приходит к [вот этой функции check_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers)

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо.

Comment: @andreymal Здравствуйте. Если можете, посоветуйте как в таком случае хранить пароли от пользовательских мейлов в БД?